# How to select specific theme to use?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, android-manifest, android-theme

I'm porting my game to android and i want have it compatible with android 4.0 but Unity using "Material" theme by default (available from 5.0). Is there any way how to force Unity to use Holo theme instead of Material theme ?
I have target API level set to 16 for maximum compability and I already tryed custom manifest, both replacing defalut one in Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk and puting one to Assets\Plugins\Android but i stll get error during building : No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen'. But i don't want use Material theme, i want use Holo theme. I know i can solve this by seting API leve higer but i want make it compatible with Android 4.1. Text below is manifest used in both locations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your settings in Unity so that when you export your Unity project to an apk, the Material theme isn't used. Off the top of my head there's a setting in Unity that allows you to set the maxSDK for Android.

Comment: Where ? If you mean API level it is set to 16 but i get build error because API level 16 is android 4.1 and in android 4.1 have only holo theme. But i have more levels of SDK installed. Problem is when unity looking for Material theme what i don't want use...Man, this driving me crazy...